# Error when using ape::root in R

Tags: r, phylogeny

I'm trying to use `root` from the `ape` package in R, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'fuseRoot' not found
```

Here is the code that isn't working:

```
mammal.trees <- lapply(mammal.trees, root, "Gal", resolve.root=TRUE)
```

I'm stumped because the same code works for another `multiPhylo` object just fine.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the output of `dput(mammal.trees[1:2])`? It helps if we can reproduce your error.